# Gridview New activity not working

Tags: android, gridview

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.programlist, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked " + result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

`mainactivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        GridView gv;
        Context context;
        ArrayList prgmName;
        public static String [] prgmNameList={"Education","Timing"};
        public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.educ,R.drawable.bus};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
            gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I click an item it shows "You Clicked This". However, I need to go to a new page when clicking an item.

When I am using `startactivity` it also shows an error.

Comment: put your `MainActivity` code

Comment: don't put code in comment

Comment: Provide the code for the intent which you are using to navigate to another activity. Also make sure you have already created a second activity to transit from 1st activity.

Comment: How to put code then @Rustam

Comment: You should put in question part itself as you included `CustomAdapter ` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to start another activity and let this activity handle the action corresponding to the selected item:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
   //Add the position to the intent to be used in the second activity.
   intent.putExtra("position", position);
   context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to go New activity

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.about_us:
                    Intent intentAbout = new Intent("com.clouditbd.payme.AboutUs"); //AboutUs is new activity class
                    startActivity(intentAbout);
                    return true;
                case R.id.exit:
                    if (isConnected()) {
                        Intent intentExit = new Intent("com.clouditbd.payme.Logout");
                        startActivity(intentExit);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```